# If Two Attached Property (same) defined in one element which one will be Applied

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, attached-properties

```
<StackPanel TextElement.FontSize="70" TextBlock.FontSize="30" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button MinWidth="75" Margin="10" Content="Help"/>
            <Button MinWidth="75" Margin="10" Content="OK" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

I have defined two FontSize in the Stack-Panel so that using PropertyValueInheritance Button will get its value for FontSize. But which FontSize is applied at Run-Time and why?

Answer (score 0):

The last one, in your case the second of the two `FontSize`, will determine the size of the buttons' content, because it will overwrite the other at *runtime*.

```
 TextBlock.FontSize="30"
```

while the designer is showing the more recently modified

Comment: on what bases override happen at run-time, is it always like "the property defined latter will always override the property define earlier"?

Comment: On the basis of the execution order by which the different component parts are rendered in the layout at runtime. If you have other use cases that you didn't specify, edit your post or accept the answer, if it fits your example, and then ask another question.